# Remove array value on unclick

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have check-boxes that save the index of that checkbox on click in an array. I am trying to add functionality so that when the checkbox is unchecked the value is removed from the array.

Below is the loop that saves the checkbox value to the array I am then comparing the selected array with another tag array later in my script. So if the user clicks the checkbox and then unclicks it the value is still true.

```
                            CheckBox[] setOfCheckBoxes = new CheckBox[]
                                          {
                                        (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1),
                                        (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2),      
                                        (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3),
                                        (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4),
                                         };
            for (int i = 0; i < setOfCheckBoxes.length; i++) { 

                 final int index = i;
                     setOfCheckBoxes[i].setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){    
                       public void onClick(View v) {      
                       selected[index] = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
                       }
                    });
                }
```

Should I do the unChecked in the same loop?

Comment: It would be nicer/clear if you add selected[i] = setOfCheckBoxes[i].isChecked(); inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already doing it.

```
selected[index] = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
```

If your checkbox is checked, your `selected[index]` will be `true` else it will be `false`.

I'm assuming you have initialized `selected[]` as `new boolean[setOfCheckBoxes.length]` and set them all to false.

Comment: But I think that if they check it and then uncheck it the index is still in selected.

Comment: You are correct selected is a boolen but set to the length of tags array that I compare the two later.

Comment: The click listener should fire whether they check it or not ..so I would assume the selected[index] should toggle between true and false.

Comment: Let me go back and add a toast and see whats in there. I am building a url with parameters based off the check boxes and I am getting unwanted results. Back to testing. thanks so far for your help +1

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You can also get the status of checkboxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < setOfCheckBoxes.length; i++) { 
  selected[i] = setOfCheckBoxes[i].isChecked();
}
```

Comment: @Denoteone , Instead of setting the onClicklisteners I recommend doing the above in your final event that creates the URL. More straighter implementation would be to use the values directly for ur purpose than putting into an array and then using it.